# Discord.py not calling error handler, and not printing traceback until the program is terminated

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having some issues regarding error handling with discord.py. I have set up the following command:

```
class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""

@commands.command(name='connect', aliases=['join'])
async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None):
    if not channel:
        try:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        except AttributeError:
            raise InvalidVoiceChannel(
                'No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel'
                ' or join one.'
            )

    vc = ctx.voice_client

    if vc:
        if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
            return
        try:
            await vc.move_to(channel)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            raise VoiceConnectionError(
                f'Moving to channel: <{channel}> timed out.'
            )
    else:
        try:
            await channel.connect()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            raise VoiceConnectionError(
                f'Connecting to channel: <{channel}> timed out.'
            )

    )
    await ctx.send(f'Connected to: **{channel}**', delete_after=20)
```

When it is run and the author is connected to a voice channel, all is well and the bot connects to the channel. However, when the author is not connected to a voice channel (and one is not passed as an argument), the error does not *appear* to be raised, and the error handler (below) is not called:

```
async def __error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        try:
            return await ctx.send(
                'This command can not be used in private messages.'
            )
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
    elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
        await ctx.send(
            'Error connecting to voice channel. Please make sure you are'
            ' in a valid channel or provide me with one.'
        )
    else:
        raise error
```

Once I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the bot, then I see the following printed:

```
Ignoring exception in command connect:                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danth/Code/discord-sounds/sounds/cogs/music.py", line 269, in connect_
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/danth/Code/.virtualenvs/discord-sounds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
      await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
    File "/home/danth/Code/.virtualenvs/discord-sounds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
      await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
    File "/home/danth/Code/.virtualenvs/discord-sounds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 79, in wrapped
      ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/danth/Code/discord-sounds/sounds/cogs/music.py", line 272, in connect_
    'No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel'
cogs.music.InvalidVoiceChannel: No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.
```

Why doesn't the error handler get called, and why doesn't the traceback appear immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be referring to an old example or documentation.  The [list of special Cog methods](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#special-methods) implies you should use [`cog_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_command_error) instead.